# Class is not key value coding-compliant for the key, when setting values for an object that has a member which conforms to a custom class

Tags: swift, swift3

I am trying to use `setValuesForKeys` on an object that has a member which conforms to a custom class, which is why I believe I get the below error, how could I get around this ? I prefer to do this in a native way if simple or can I use any library/framework to resolve this.

> this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key
>   availabilityTimesDict

```
func convertJSONDataToSwiftObject(){

    let registrationDataDict =
        [
            "firstName": "Joe Bloggs",
            "alternateNames": ["Joe", "Bloggs"],

            "availabilityTimesDict" : [
                "Friday" : ["times":[["startTime":"9:00 AM","endTime":"1:30 PM"],["startTime":"2:30 PM","endTime":"6:00 PM"]],"weekday":"Friday","available":true],
                "Monday" : ["times":[["startTime":"11:00 AM","endTime":"1:30 PM"]], "weekday":"Monday","available":true]]
        ] as [String : AnyObject]

    var profileDetailsObject = ProfileDetails()

    profileDetailsObject.setValuesForKeys(registrationDataDict as [String : AnyObject])  // SOURCE OF ERROR

}


class ProfileDetails: NSObject{

    var firstName              :   String!
    var alternateNames         :   [String]!
    var availabilityTimesDict  :   [String : AvailabilityTimes.DailyTimes]!
}

class AvailabilityTimes: NSObject{
    struct Times{
        var startTime : String?
        var endTime   : String?

        func convertToDictionary() -> Dictionary<String, Any> {
            return [
                "startTime" : self.startTime as Any,
                "endTime"   : self.endTime as Any
            ]
        }
    }

    struct DailyTimes{
        let weekday : String
        var available : Bool
        var times = [Times]()
        mutating func update(times: [Times]){
            self.times = times
        }

        func convertToDictionary() -> Dictionary<String, Any> {
            return [
                "weekday"   : self.weekday,
                "available" : self.available,
                "times"     : self.times.map{$0.convertToDictionary()}
            ]
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: I recommend not to use KVO. Swift is strict type language, so set every property separately or use initializer that is best approach. It'll be easy to debug and understanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is very complicated with the KVO ,

I can clearly see the mistake is with   **"availabilityTimesDict" :**

***You Can check it with comment availabilityTimesDict from kvo dict***

It is better and more redable if you are using initalizer rather then KVO , it will also helpful in future if any change comes you can do it easily with few modifications

Here is example code

```
class ProfileDetails: NSObject{

var firstName              :   String!
var alternateNames         :   [String]!
var availabilityTimesDict  :   [String : AvailabilityTimes.DailyTimes]!

private override init() {
     super.init()
}

required init(with FirstName : String,alterName:[String],availabilityTimesDict:[String : AvailabilityTimes.DailyTimes]) {
    super.init()
    self.firstName = FirstName;
    self.alternateNames = alterName;
    self.availabilityTimesDict = availabilityTimesDict;

}
}

class AvailabilityTimes: NSObject{
    struct Times{
        var startTime : String?
        var endTime   : String?

        func convertToDictionary() -> Dictionary<String, Any> {
            return [
                "startTime" : self.startTime as Any,
                "endTime"   : self.endTime as Any
            ]
        }
    }

    struct DailyTimes{
        let weekday : String
        var available : Bool
        var times = [Times]()
        mutating func update(times: [Times]){
            self.times = times
        }

        func convertToDictionary() -> Dictionary<String, Any> {
            return [
                "weekday"   : self.weekday,
                "available" : self.available,
                "times"     : self.times.map{$0.convertToDictionary()}
            ]
        }

    }
}

var availTimes = AvailabilityTimes.Times.init(startTime: "9:00 AM", endTime: "1:30 PM")
var avaiblityTimes = AvailabilityTimes.DailyTimes.init(weekday: "Friday", available: true, times:[availTimes] )

var times = ["Firday":avaiblityTimes]

var profileDetailsObject = ProfileDetails.init(with: "Joe Bloggs", alterName: ["Joe", "Bloggs"], availabilityTimesDict: times)
profileDetailsObject.firstName = "test"
```